# What is the difference between M11 and M21 cells in a transformation Matrix?

Tags: c#-4.0, matrix, svg, system.drawing

I need to interpret an SVG input data and identify the displayed points.

In the SVG format, any point may be part of a group (  element ) to which transformations (translate/rotate/scale) may be applied. For every point, I need to bubble up and apply transformation of every ancestor, in order to find the position that the point has in the rendering. After reading some web pages on the subject (and trying to remember from school), I understand that the usual way to do this in .NET is to use 3x3 mathematical matrices, so I try to figure out the System.Windows.Media.Matrix class.

It's been a while since I took Math, and I can't recall this one particular detail.

I typed up the following code in LINQPad:

```
var matrix = new Matrix(1,1,1,6,0,0);
var matrix2 = new Matrix(2,1,0,6,0,0);
var matrix3 = new Matrix(0,1,2,6,0,0);
var pts = new[]{
        new System.Windows.Point(0,0),
        new System.Windows.Point(1,1),
        new System.Windows.Point(2,2),
        new System.Windows.Point(3,3),
        new System.Windows.Point(4,4),
        new System.Windows.Point(5,5)
        }.ToArray();
pts.Select(org=>new{org,changed=matrix.Transform(org),changed2=matrix2.Transform(org),changed3=matrix3.Transform(org)}).Dump("Transformation Samples");
```

... and trying out different values in the Matrix constructor.

However it seems that these values have no impact on the final result.
new Matrix(**1**,1,**1**,6,0,0);
new Matrix(**2**,1,**0**,6,0,0);
new Matrix(**0**,1,**2**,6,0,0);
(same is true for arguments 2 and 4)

The only thing that seems to matter is the **sum of the two** (which in this case is 2). I assume that this is due to my limited input data and that given other input data, some difference could be seen that would make sense in some visual tranformation.

Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the section in the SVG spec about how transform matrixes work will be of use to you?

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined

Comment: At least this told me that scaling is handled by the M11 and M22 cells. Though I still don't see the pitfalls that I evaded, it resolved the apparent ambiguity.